# Change value of FlutterFormBuilder before sending

Tags: flutter, dart, formbuilder

I've got this piece of code that lets you choose from some options in a checkbox. When those results are sent, the `valueTransformer` should modify those results by changing `val`.

```
GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> _fbKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();
//* ----------------------------------------------------
FormBuilderCheckboxGroup(
   attribute: 'entities',
   options:
       namelist.map((e) => FormBuilderFieldOption(value: e)).toList(),
   valueTransformer: (val){
       if((val!=null)&& (val.length!=0)){
           List<String> selectedentities=List<String>.from(val);
           val=List<dynamic>.from(NamestoIDs(selectedentities));
           print(val);
       }
),
```

`print(val);` prints what I wanted to assign, a list of Strings:
`[Izj630pFN, UD6aVde7q, ZWiTrfxI]`

Problem: when I send the info and then read `_fbKey.currentState.value`, it appears to be null.

UPDATE: this solves the problem.

```
valueTransformer: (val)=> List<dynamic>.from(NamestoIDs(List<String>.from(val)))
```